# Two overlaying svg texts - select and copy just one

Tags: text, svg, d3.js, overlay, selection

I have two overlaying svg texts. One is black and the second one has a white stroke for making a little background behind the text. I am using d3.js to generate this svg. The problem is when I select the black text it will select both texts and when I copy them I have duplicated data in my clipboard.

I have tried to make the background unselectable with css and javascript but there is still double copy in some cases.

My first solution that doesn't work

```
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

also tried this params

```
unselectable="on" 
onselectstart="return false"
onmousedown='return false;'
// in css
pointer-events:none
```

Comment: Add your markup to the question including what you're doing in css to make it unselectable.

Comment: If the second text is just there to create a shadow then you're best not having it at all and creating the shadow using a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the actual text content in the markup, use a `<use>` statement to duplicate and re-style the graphic.

You say:

> I tried to make the background unselectable with css and javascript but there is in some cases still double copy.

I assume that means you used `pointer-events:none` or used JavaScript to force the browser to ignore clicks on the extra text element.  That prevents the user from starting or ending a selection in that element when selecting with the mouse.  However, it doesn't prevent that text element from being included inside a selection range, if your selection starts from before the element and continues until after.  It also doesn't prevent the user from selecting the text with keyboard or accessibility technologies.

You could use more complex JavaScript to manipulate the user's selection directly, but the `<use>` technique is much simpler.  I've tested the following on latest Chrome, Firefox, and IE, and in each case only one copy of the text is included in the selection.

```css
svg {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 10em;
    font-size: xx-large;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
}
text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Select all
<svg>
    <use stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
         xlink:href="#double-this" />
    <text id="double-this" x="1ex" dy="1em">Text Content</text>
</svg>
in this snippet and paste below.
</p>
<textArea rows="10"></textArea>
```

Same example as a JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3htr7btx/1/

One thing to note: Because of style inheritance rules, you cannot set any styles you want to over-ride (`stroke` and `stroke-width` in the example) directly on the re-used `<text>` element.  They have to be inherited for that element, so that the copy will inherit the styles you set on the `<use>` element.

Also be aware that you cannot re-use a `<tspan>` or `<textPath>` element, it has to be the parent `<text>` that actually draws content to the page.  SVG 1 and 1.1 define an alternative way of repeating text content, the `<tref>` element, but it was never implemented in most browsers and will probably be deprecated or made obsolete in SVG 2.

Comment: Thank you. But I have problem with this solution. What if I have more than one? The stroke looks like this http://i.imgur.com/bItoxoP.png

Comment: Ok I set unique ID for every text and add it to link and it's working now.